# Skobbler Demo Application(SDK Demo version 3) crashes

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Skobbler Demo application (for SDK Versoin 3) is crashing at following line in Splash activity:

```
SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(), this);
```

and Console didplay following log for this crash:

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String):-2 in call to FindClass from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String)

at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.(SourceFile:68)
  at com.skobbler.sdkdemo.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:79)

*79 line number points to:* SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(), this);

I also downloaded the apk from Skobbler demo for Demo project, which also crashed.

Comment: On what device/OS are you testing?

Comment: I am testing on Samsung Tab OS version 5.0.2 and did also test on Nexus 4 OS version 5.1.1